# Javascript output variable: guidance on best practice?

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to Javascript and have noticed that in tutorials, people use several alternate approaches in dealing with output.

Let's use a simple example and say that we want to console.log() each name in an array of student names, one name per line.

**Approach #1:** console.log() each individual iteration

```
var names = ["Alan", "Barbara", "Charlie", "Denise"]

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
   console.log(names[i]);
}
```

**Approach #2:** define and use an output variable to console.log() each individual iteration

```
var names = ["Alan", "Barbara", "Charlie", "Denise"]
var output = "";

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
   output = names[i];
   console.log(output);
}
```

**Approach #3:** define and use an output variable, but then store each name with a line break into the output variable, and then console.log() the output after the entire for loop is completed

```
var names = ["Alan", "Barbara", "Charlie", "Denise"]
var output = "";

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
   output += names[i] + "\n";
}
console.log(output);
```

All of these work in my browser, but I'm sure there must be some subtle differences which I am overlooking.  I would love some guidance on best practices and discussion on which of these approaches is preferred, either generally or in specific situations, and which to avoid or favor / commit to muscle memory.  Thank you!

Comment: Go with whatever you feel comfortable. There is no hard and fast rule that a certain approach should be used. Yes the type of approach varies depending on your requirement ofcourse.

Comment: There is no best practice for outputting to the console for debugging purposes, whatever is easiest for you and produces the correct output is fine.

Comment: I think most developers will use `#1`. You may occasionally see a variation of `#3` but with `Array#push` and `Array#join`.

Comment: I guess there is no need to `console.log` each item insides of array. I understand that this is not real world example, but still does not fit in mind with `console.log`.
I would just `console.log` entire array and look on it via some dev tools. 
But if I had to choose one of provided samples I would choose none. There is still better ways to `console.log` items with less code. Like `names.forEach(n => console.log(n))`

Answer (score -1):

The recommended practice is to avoid writing your own loops, where it's possible.

You don't need to do anything with your array, because you can output complex objects to the console as well:

```
console.log(["Alan", "Barbara", "Charlie", "Denise"]);
```

But if you need to put each name in a new line use `Array.join` like this:

```
var names = ["Alan", "Barbara", "Charlie", "Denise"];
console.log(names.join("\n"));
```

If you are dealing with an array of objects, then you can call `Array.map` before `join`, so you can transform them to strings.

If you would like to keep the structure of the code similar to what you provided in the question, you can use `forEach`:

```
var names = ["Alan", "Barbara", "Charlie", "Denise"];
names.forEach(function(name){
    console.log(name);
});
```